# Keras cross entropy loss with missing labels in multi-objective training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras neural network, using the Functional API, that has multiple outputs and multiple loss functions (some regression, some multi-class classification). I will always have a label for at least one of the outputs in training but commonly at least one will be missing.

I'm trying to write a custom categorical cross entropy loss function:

```
def custom_error_function(y_true, y_pred):
    bool_finite = y_true != -1
    
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    one_hotted = one_hot(np.int(boolean_mask(y_true, bool_finite)), depth=5)
    return loss(one_hotted, boolean_mask(y_pred, bool_finite, axis=1))
```

where y_pred and y_true should have the same shape ([n_samples_in_batch, n_classes (5)]) and a value of `-1` for y_true indicates missing.

But when I run this, I get

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/var/folders/pn/c0hwfk8n7q9442628b1g_p1r0000gp/T/ipykernel_13239/802342025.py", line 12, in custom_error_function  *
        return loss(one_hotted, boolean_mask(y_pred, bool_finite, axis=1))

    ValueError: Shapes (5,) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

I'm a bit flummoxed and would appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `axis=1` in the loss call, the following should work:

```
def custom_error_function(y_true, y_pred):
    bool_finite = y_true != -1
    
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    return loss(tf.boolean_mask(y_true, bool_finite), tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, bool_finite))
```